# jquery: select children of a variable only

Tags: jquery

Loading new posts with infinite scroll and positioning them with masonry js.

Here's some commented code.

```
function (newElements) {


    $.adaptiveBackground.run(); // run adaptive backgrounds on all new posts so as to colour them the approximate colour of the image about to be loaded
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ // hiding new posts until they're positioned properly after images are loaded
        opacity:0
    });

    var hideimages = $(".figure > img").hide(); // lets hide the images of new posts loaded

    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {



        $newElems.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }); //images now loaded, posts moved into correct masonry position, posts now un-hidden 

        var hideimages = $(".figure > img").delay( 1000 ).fadeIn(1000); // lets fade the images in after 1 second 


       $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );

    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is this line `var hideimages = $(".figure > img").hide();`, I only want to hide the images inside the newElements(ie posts just loaded in), but I'm not quite sure how to work with children of variables nor can I find the correct documentation.

This *works* but obviously it hides any image inside .figure of posts that have already been loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [specify a context for your selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context):

```
$('.figure > img', $newElems).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason, your answer works perfectly, I'll accept it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addClass()` to give a special class to all newly-added elements, and target that class selector rather than the more general `.figure > img` selector (then `removeClass()`).

You could alternately use the context selector parameter that Jason P's answer describes, or use the `.filter($newElems)` method which will function about the same way.

Comment: I did think of adding classes, but isn't that less efficient than simply targeting a selector that already exists?

Comment: @andy Marginally but there is not a big difference between efficiency of those two selectors.  The overhead with `addClass` and `removeClass` IS a tangible thing, but in most cases it will be totally negligible.  I didn't remember the context parameter until after I saw Jason's post so I'd recommend his answer (although using classes will make the code a bit more readable).